# How to highlight certain values in an Excel Column with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the following code in which for Column A, I am trying to do a red highlight for any value that equals 102, a yellow highlight for any value that equals 101, and a blue highlight for any value that equals 100.

I think the issue is in my last section (###Super If Statement##), so just want to see what is the right code for the parameters in the paragraph above?
Thanks

```
#Open Up the Workbook#
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("c:\scripts\test.xlsx")
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$rows = $worksheet.range("A1").currentregion.rows.count

#A Formula#
$worksheet.range("A2:A$rows").formula = "=B2+100"
[void]$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).select()
$excel.visible = $true

#Today + 1 Formula#
$worksheet.range("C2:C$rows").formula = "=TODAY()+1"
[void]$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).select()
$excel.visible = $true

#INJECTED WITH A POISON#
$worksheet.range("C1").formula = "The Official Formula"
[void]$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).select()
$excel.visible = $true

#Set up a filter
$headerRange = $worksheet.Range("a1","c1")
$headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null
$Excel.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true

#Super If Statement##
IF ($worksheet.range("A2:A$rows") -eq "102") {
  $worksheet.range.Interior.ColorIndex =3} 
ElseIF ($worksheet.range("A2:A$rows") -eq "101") {
  $worksheet.range.Interior.ColorIndex =6} 
ElseIF ($worksheet.range("A2:A$rows") -eq "100") {
  $worksheet.range.Interior.ColorIndex =5}
```

Comment: In the ## Super If Statement## section, I've added the closing `)` and I don't receive any error messages. But when the excel sheet pop up, the values don't highlight even if its specifically stated for (e.g.102 should be red shaded)

Comment: is there mix up between 102 & "102"? I ran your code locally, it seems ok.
But I did use a foreach to iterate through the headers instead of your If/else switches.

Comment: I don't think so. I've replaced the values for ones without quotation and same situation pops up. No error message though. What was the code you used with foreach though? That might helpful @SAm

Comment: $ws.Range('c5:c14')|%{  if($_.text -match '101'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 5 } }

Comment: Maybe you want to evaluate what $worksheet.range("A2:A$rows") returns.

Comment: Thanks @SAm. I was able to solve it with the `foreach` code. Here is the right formula below. I'm not sure how to credit you for the answer?                                                                                            `#Super ForEach Statement ##
                                                                   
$worksheet.Range('A2:A100')|%{ if($_.text -match '102'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 3 } } 
$worksheet.Range('A2:A100')|%{ if($_.text -match '101'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 6 } } 
$worksheet.Range('A2:A100')|%{ if($_.text -match '100'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 5 } } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the @SAm sample code,  I replaced `#Super If Statement##` with the code in `##Super Foreach Statement##` as seen below. The following code is now able to execute as intended.

```
#Open Up the Workbook#
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("c:\scripts\test.xlsx")
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$rows = $worksheet.range("A1").currentregion.rows.count

#A Formula#
$worksheet.range("A2:A$rows").formula = "=B2+100"
[void]$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).select()
$excel.visible = $true

#Today + 1 Formula#
$worksheet.range("C2:C$rows").formula = "=TODAY()+1"
[void]$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).select()
$excel.visible = $true

#INJECTED WITH A POISON#
$worksheet.range("C1").formula = "The Official Formula"
[void]$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1).select()
$excel.visible = $true

#Set up a filter
$headerRange = $worksheet.Range("a1","c1")
$headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null
$Excel.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true

#Super ForEach Statement ## 
$worksheet.Range('A2:A100')|%{ if($_.text -match '102'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 3 } } 
$worksheet.Range('A2:A100')|%{ if($_.text -match '101'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 6 } } 
$worksheet.Range('A2:A100')|%{ if($_.text -match '100'){ $_.interior.colorindex = 5 } }
```